# Where to config "mail.from" in JBoss 7.1

Tags: jboss, jakarta-mail

In the JBoss AS6 we can config "mail.from" as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
  <mbean code="org.jboss.mail.MailService" name="jboss:service=Mail">
    <attribute name="JNDIName">java:/TestMail</attribute>
    <attribute name="User">someUsername</attribute>
    <attribute name="Password">somePassword</attribute>
    <attribute name="Configuration">
      <!-- A test configuration -->
      <configuration>
        <!-- Change to your mail server prototocol -->
        <property name="mail.store.protocol" value="pop3"/>
        ...
        <!-- Change to the address mail will be from  -->
        <property name="mail.from" value="testuser@middlewaremagic.com"/>

        <!-- Enable debugging output from the javamail classes -->
        <property name="mail.debug" value="true"/>
      </configuration>
    </attribute>
    <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
  </mbean>
</server>
```

Where can I config it in JBoss AS7?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this question would fit better in [superuser](https://superuser.com/). Just as a note. :-)

However a Simple question to google gave me this:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1177

I think you should use

```
<property name="mail.from">nobody@nosuchhost.nosuchdomain.com</property>
```

in the new config format.